Getter and setter ignored in a custom element
I came accross an odd problem using WebComponents and composing them. I created a minimal HTML page to reproduce the problem.
I'm basically trying to build the following structure :

custom list
containing custom items
each item containing a custom input to show the item name

My custom input is a wrapper to add label to a basic input and I use get and set on my custom input so that its value mirror the basic input value.
It works perfectly in isolation : getting and setting the value of my custom input gets and sets the value of the basic input inside it.
It also works fine inside my custom item : getting and setting its item correctly mirrors the item name on the custom input.
But when I manage items through my custom list, it breaks. The getter and setter of my custom input seem to have disappeared and fallback to a normal property with no accessors functions.
Here's the minimal code to reproduce the problem :


const customInputTemplate = document.createElement("template");
customInputTemplate.innerHTML = `
    <label id="label" for="input"></label>
    <input id="input" type="text" />
    `;

window.customElements.define("my-custom-input", class MyCustomInput extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["label"]
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(customInputTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));

    this.labelElemenet = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("label");
    this.inputElement = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("input");
  }

  get value() { // This seems to be ignored or unset in certain cases
    return this.inputElement.value;
  }

  set value(newValue) { // This also has the problem
    this.inputElement.value = newValue;
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name === "label") {
      this.labelElemenet.innerText = newValue;
    }
  }
});

const customItemTemplate = document.createElement("template");
customItemTemplate.innerHTML = `
      <li>
        <my-custom-input id="custom-input" label="Item :"></my-custom-input>
      </li>
    `;

window.customElements.define("my-custom-item", class MyCustomItem extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._item = undefined;
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(customItemTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));

    this.customInputElement = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("custom-input");
  }

  get item() {
    return this._item;
  }

  set item(newItem) {
    this._item = newItem;
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.customInputElement.value !== this.item.name) {
      this.customInputElement.value = this.item.name
    }
  }
});

const customListTemplate = document.createElement("template");
customListTemplate.innerHTML = `
      <ul>
        <slot></slot>
      </ul>
    `;

window.customElements.define("my-custom-list", class MyCustomList extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._items = [];
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(customListTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  get items() {
    return this._items;
  }

  set items(newItems) {
    this._items = newItems;
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.replaceChildren(...this.items.map(item => {
      const itemElement = document.createElement("my-custom-item");
      itemElement.item = item; // This is where things get broken
      return itemElement;
    }));
  }
});

const customInputElement = document.getElementById("my-custom-input");
customInputElement.value = "Some value for my custom input";

const customItemElement = document.getElementById("my-custom-item");
customItemElement.item = {
  id: "Z",
  name: "Some name for my custom item"
};

const listElement = document.getElementById("my-list");

listElement.items = [{
    id: "A",
    name: "Item A"
  },
  {
    id: "B",
    name: "Item B"
  },
  {
    id: "C",
    name: "Item C"
  },
];

// All inputs are empty instead of showing the item names

const firstItem = listElement.querySelector("my-custom-item");
const customInputOfFirstItem = firstItem.shadowRoot.querySelector("my-custom-input");

console.log("customInputOfFirstItem.value = ", customInputOfFirstItem.value); // Correctly logs "Item A"

// Trying to force value
customInputOfFirstItem.value = "Updated item A";
console.log("After forcing value, customInputOfFirstItem.value = ", customInputOfFirstItem.value); // Correctly logs "Updated item A"

// But ...
const originalInput = customInputOfFirstItem.shadowRoot.getElementById("input");
console.log("Original input value = ", originalInput.value); // Logs empty value
// Forcing it
originalInput.value = "Forced inside value for item A";
console.log("After forcing inside value, customInputOfFirstItem.value = ", customInputOfFirstItem.value); // Still logs "Updated item A"

// It's acting as if getter (line 37) and setter (line 41) where ignored or somewhat unset in the process
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Web Component</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Custom input, works fine</h3>
  <my-custom-input id="my-custom-input" label="Custom input"></my-custom-input>

  <h3>Custom item, also works fine</h3>
  <my-custom-item id="my-custom-item"></my-custom-item>

  <h3>Inside custom list, does not work</h3>
  <my-custom-list id="my-list"></my-custom-list>
</body>

</html>




You're using an id in the template which would result in duplicate id="input" throughout?

I replaced id in the templates with classes and use querySelector to get the elements but it still behave the same.

@pilchard Each element has its own shadow root, shouldn't they have independent ID namespaces?

Your code example contains syntax errors. Please fix them so it's executable.

@htor Somehow the stackoverflow parser doesn't like private  members starting  with #. I replaced them with  public ones and the code example is now executable.

Nah, it did work before, but the edit by @Barmar broken the private member declarations

Sorry about that. I use it to clean up indentation, but it doesn't know about private properties and optional chaining.
